# Javascript retrieve element by it's properties

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Every HTML element has offset values. Can I return an element that has, for example, `offsetLeft > 10`?

Have never heard of this feature, therefore the question.

I'm aware that this can be done with loops, but those are slow. Had an idea about XPath, but cannot find anything related to properties within reference.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. No need for outdated browser compatibility- HTML5'ish can do.

Comment: You can walk around the all DOM tree and check the property / value for each element.

Comment: Even `querySelectorAll()` cannot match elements from their `offsetLeft` property, therefore the implementation of this feature will probably have to take the "slow" approach and walk the document tree anyway.

Comment: Whatever you do, at some level there is some kind of a loop. Do *something* and see whether the solution is slow or not. If it is too slow, refactor it. Loops are not slow by themselves. It is important what is *inside* the loop.

Comment: @Felix King, but if there's a native function or a function that looks "fast"- the loop'ish feeling fades..

Comment: @Felix King, I've already done something... Adding *5 attributes* to each *element* within a *loop* of +/-600 elements for about 5 times (different parent elements) `onload()` can freeze the browser for a while (or tab in Chrome's case). At least it can be retrieved almost instantly with XPath later, but the loading time is not healthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do this that does not involve looping of some form. You could do it in standard JS with something along these lines:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*"),
    myElems = [];
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   if(elems[i].offsetLeft > 10) myElems.push(elems[i]);
}
```

Or, if you're using jQuery you can do it with a little less code (but it's probably even slower!):

```
var myElems = $("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).offset().left > 10;
});
```

If you think about it, you want to select all of the elements in a document with a certain property value. That's always going to involve a loop at some point, whether you write it yourself or not, as every element has to be checked.

Comment: +1 for being the only person so far to post a non-jQuery solution for a non-jQuery question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this page yet? [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can easily select attributes of elements

```
<div>Dont find me</div>
<div this="yes">Find me</div>

$('div[this=yes]'); // will select the second div
```

The problem you are going to run into is things like offset and position are calculated values, and not stored in the dom with the elements upfront. If you need to select by this, I would suggest putting them as attributes inside of the dom element itself. Then the above method with work just fine.

Comment: In your example `this` is not an property, is an attribute. In question: about property check.

Comment: I can select attributes with XPath also, but attributes are incredibly slow when added to 1000+ elements. It's OK after the addition, but while adding, browser freezes until the operation is complete.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest the best way to do this would be to extend jQuery's selectors. Something like this works well:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{

        offsetLeft: function(a,i,m) {
            if(!m[3]||!(/^(<|>|=)\d+$/).test(m[3])) {return false;}
            var offsetLeft = $(a).offset().left;
            return m[3].substr(0,1) === '>' ?
                 offsetLeft > parseInt(m[3].substr(1),10) :
                     m[3].substr(0,1) === '<' ? offsetLeft < parseInt(m[3].substr(1),10) :
                         offsetLeft == parseInt(m[3].substr(1),10);
        }
});
```

This would allow you to select elements using syntax such as

`$('span:offsetLeft(>10)')`

or

`$('.someClass:offsetLeft(<10)')`

or even

`$('.someClass:offsetLeft(=10)')`

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/X4CkC/

Should add that this hooks into jQuery's selectors which are generally quite fast, but no doubt somewhere deep within there is a loop going on. There' no way of avoiding that.

Comment: `var tags = ["javascript", "html", "web-development", "dom"]; for (var i=0;i<tags.length;i++) if (tags[i] == "jquery") alert("The OP wants jQuery in this answer")`. Or, more relevant to you: `if (jQuery.inArray(["javascript", "html", "web-development", "dom"], "jquery")) alert("The OP wants jQuery in this answer");`

Comment: Which function gets extended by this? Like, does it end up in `querySelector()` or where?

Comment: @Matt, @Mr. Dis - You may well downvote, thats your choice, but this is a perfectly valid solution as jQuery provides all the tools you need to do something like the OP wants to do. Just because he doesnt tag his post `jQuery` doesnt mean he's not open to a solution involving it. He may not be aware of it.

Comment: @Tom - This is an extension to a widely used framework called `jQuery`. It helps in developing cross-browser javascript solutions and centres around `selectors` which enable you to find specific elements in the dom. My code extends these selectors to add a new one allowing you to find "elements with an offset greater than, less than or equal to a numeric value"

Comment: No need for such a deep explanation. But jQuery is still javascript, and the function that selects those elements are javascript too, except that jQuery gives it a little more extra to make it slower. So I was thinking, what is the native javascript function that get's extended with this functionality by jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do it with jQuery

```
$("*").each(function(index, elem){
    if($(this).offset().left > 10){
        // do something here with $(this)
    }
});
```

Comment: but I'm not sure that this can be done without loop, even in html5 there is no method to select elements by property (with querySelector you can select by attribute)

Comment: And where is jQuery mentioned in the question?